# How to sum hours and group by Employee ID and Service

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

I am trying to to group employees and the services they provide and sum their hours. For example, if an employee Josh Hutchinson works on Cleaning Room then the sum of their hours should show 42.58 hours.
I have tried the following query, but it separates it out for each day:

```
SELECT 
[Service Provider Employee ID]
,[ISP Program]
,[Service Provider]
,SUM([Duration Min])/60
FROM [EXPECTED_HOURS].[dbo].['Report Result-1$']
GROUP BY
[Service Provider Employee ID] 
,[ISP Program]
,[Service Provider]
,[Duration Min]
```

This is what it outputs:[image]

I want it to show:

```
10-emp two      | Cleaning Room         | Hutchinson,Josh  |        42.58
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Remove `[Duration Min]` from the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Wow that was literally it. I thought I had tried that and was getting the error about "not contained in either an aggregate function of the group by clause". But when I tried it again, it worked! No wonder I was going crazy. Thank you!!